# Monitoring in dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am implementing a monitoring on dashboard using softlayer api. 
To check a current server status, I've used the API below and count them.

```
Baremetal server : hw.asService(client).getServerPowerState();
Virtual server : guest.getPowerState().getKeyName();
```

The result of status is "on" or "off". (running or halt for VM)

How can I know the number of recovering ?

[image: Monitoring on dashboard]

Comment: do you mean by "recovering" when the server is reloading or updating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following request:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getObject?objectMask=mask[networkMonitorUpHardware,networkMonitorUpVirtualGuests,        networkMonitorRecoveringHardware,              networkMonitorRecoveringHardware(SoftLayer_Hardware_Server)[                  activeTransactions[                      transactionGroup  ]  ], networkMonitorDownHardware[                  hardwareStatus,                  datacenter[                      longName  ]  ],  networkMonitorDownHardware(SoftLayer_Hardware_Server)[                  activeTransactions[transactionGroup ]   ],              networkMonitorRecoveringVirtualGuests,              networkMonitorDownVirtualGuests  ]

Method: GET
```

**Reference:**
[SoftLayer_Account - datatypes](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Account)

**Properties involved in the mask:**

> - networkMonitorDownHardware
> - networkMonitorDownVirtualGuests
> - networkMonitorRecoveringHardware
> - networkMonitorRecoveringVirtualGuests
> - networkMonitorUpHardware
> - networkMonitorUpVirtualGuests

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean by "recovering", I do not renember have seen such status in softlayer.

I think you mean when a transaction is running  (e.g. when the server or VSI has been modified or reloaded) you can get that information using these methods:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getActiveTransaction
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/getActiveTransaction

The methods return empty when none transaction is running.

Regards

Comment: When I logged in "control.softlayer.com", there is a circle graph in the bottom of dashboard as I captured. It counts "recovering" as well. I guess it is the number of active transaction.

Comment: Oh I see, well that circle graph is not displaying the information you think. It displays the status of the monitorings, you can try the answer sent by mcruz, in oder to get the down servers sum the amount of items displayed networkMonitorDownHardware + networkMonitorDownVirtualGuests. For UP sum networkMonitorUpHardware + networkMonitorUpVirtualGuests. And for recovering sum networkMonitorRecoveringHardware + networkMonitorRecoveringVirtualGuests.